# Equiv to get week of year by datepart in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime

I have a code in vb

```
var weekOfYear=DateAndTime.DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, date, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday, FirstWeekOfYear.FirstFullWeek);
```

which is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127415.aspx .

I caną find nothing equivalent to this in c¤, but I don't want to create new algorithm, which I think would have some bugs :)

Which method should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static int GetWeekNumber(DateTime dtPassed)
{
        CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dtPassed, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        return weekNum;
}
```

this can help

Comment: Good answer! Keep in mind, that the calendar week number is not [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/date_and_time_format.htm) conform. See also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.getweekofyear.aspx)

Comment: This is actually wrong! It should say DayOfWeek.Sunday, it's easy to verify just by comparing with the datediff("ww",date) response.

Comment: Comparing VB: `DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, d, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday, FirstWeekOfYear.FirstFourDays)` with result of the above and it gives the same result - it should be noted that this depends on your culture and what is relevant in your country.
`var fi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo; return fi.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(value, fi.CalendarWeekRule, fi.FirstDayOfWeek);` would consider the (in windows) user selected culture.
So @Rob could actually be both correct and wrong at the same time here, depending on where in the world you are.

Answer (score 3):

You can always include the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly in your C# project and use the same methods you were using in VB.NET.